# How to substract on sum() field from rows "grouped by"

Tags: mysql

Having the following table

```
+------------------------+
| id | product_id | units|
+------------------------+
|  1 | 6949       |   3  |
|  2 | 6949       |   7  |
|  3 | 6912       |   0  |
|  . |   .        |   .  |
+------------------------+
```

I want to count how many units are there linked to the product id, so I use the following query:

> SELECT id, product_id, SUM(units) AS units FROM table GROUP BY product_id;

Which will return

```
+------------------------+
| id | product_id | units|
+------------------------+
|  1 | 6949       |   10 |
|  2 | 6912       |   0  |
+------------------------+
```

**How could I use "update" to substract 1 unit from any product using its product_id? Thanks**

Comment: That query will return a syntax error.

Comment: `UPDATE` is used to actually change a value in your table. If you want to do that then you need to be specific on which row you want to change the units. It cannot be updated on a `SUM`

Comment: @isaace that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I don't mind which row is affected as long as the sum() is consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I forgot to menction what I care about is the sum() result, not if the units field of every row is correct. I was afraid a simple update would affect all rows with that product_id so the query would be

> UPDATE table SET units = units - 1 WHERE product_id = 6949 **LIMIT 1**;

Answer (score 1):

Your question is just asking for a basic `GROUP BY` query, and here a valid one:

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    SUM(units) AS units
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    product_id;
```

But your question has a twist, because the `id` appearing in the sample result set actually appears to be a row number, ordered by one of the `id` values in each product group.  We can try writing this query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(id)) id,
    product_id,
    SUM(units) AS units
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    product_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: thanks for your answer but that's not what I was asking

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UPDATE table SET units = units - 1 WHERE product_id = ?
```

Comment: that would affect all rows with that product_id and it's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to substract 1 from only one of those rows

Answer (score 1):

The output of your query doesn't reflect the contents of your table, the id field for product `6912` can not be `2` unless it's a rownum as @Tim suggests. I'm guessing it's a typo, so to explicitly uses the id in the results table lets explicitly choose the one we want;

```
select min(id) min_id, product_id, sum(units) agg_units, sum(units) - 1 agg_units_minus_one from product group by product_id order by min_id;

+------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id   | product_id | agg_units | agg_units_minus_one |
+------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|    1 |       6949 |        10 |                   9 |
|    3 |       6912 |         0 |                  -1 |
+------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Now if you *really* want to update the units we at least have an unique id/product combo to use and a value to assign, but I suspect this is not what you want (a future aggregations will be wrong).

Comment: Not a bad approach, but not what I was looking for, thanks